# Magento 2 - Navegación por capas, sin resultados

Tags: magento2

Tengo un problema con la navegación por capas de Magento 2.1.8 en el sentido de que no se muestran los resultados tras filtrar por varios atributos personalizados.

El único filtro que me devuelve productos es el de precio y eso porque el precio es un atributo que viene por defecto con la tienda.

He intentado limpiar la caché, modificar los permisos de escritura según la documentación de magento, ejecutar un :

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex

No sé que puede ser.

Adjunto 2 captura de pantalla donde se muestran los filtros y el resultado que obtengo tras la filtración:

**Filtros:**

[image: Navegación por capas Magento 2.1.8]

**Resultados:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Solo funciona con el precio? funciona por marca o algún otro atributo predeterminado?

Comment: Hola Shaz, gracias por tu respuesta. Solo me funciona con el precio y es el único atributo que sigue activo de los que suelen venir por defecto. Los demás los eliminé porque no los necesitaba y he creado algunos personalizados como por ejemplo: laboratorio y formato. a la hora de crearlos puse la opción: Filterable (with results) pero aún así no funciona.

Comment: ¿qué tipos de atributos son laboratorio y formato? no ayudará mucho, pero ¿puedes agregar una captura de pantalla de la navegación por capas?

Comment: La agrego ahora mismo a la publicación. Los atributos son de tipo dropdown simple.

Comment: Curioso pero típico en Magento, ¿tienes alguna URL donde pueda ver el comportamiento?